# How to ask permissions for camera and gallery at the same time in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app where I need to request gallery access and camera access at the same time on tap of a button.i.e. one after another.I am new to swift. Is there a proper way to do that?

This is my code I am currently using:

```
func checkPermissions() {
    
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        // Request read-write access to the user's photo library.
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { status in
            switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                // The user hasn't determined this app's access.
                print("Not Determined")
                self.showAlertToOpenSettings(type: 1)
            case .restricted:
                // The system restricted this app's access.
                print("Resticted")
                self.showAlertToOpenSettings(type: 1)
            case .denied:
                // The user explicitly denied this app's access.
                print("Denied")
                self.showAlertToOpenSettings(type: 1)
            case .authorized:
                // The user authorized this app to access Photos data.
                print("authorised")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.openPhotoPicker()
                }
            case .limited:
                // The user authorized this app for limited Photos access.
                print("Limited")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showLimitedLibraryAlert()
                }
//                self.openLimitedLibrary()
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        //Camera
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
            if response {
                //access granted
            } else {
                self.showAlertToOpenSettings(type: 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that if user selects options from photoLibrary permission alert, the camera alert appears immediately  after selecting any option. For example if I select limited option ("Select Photos") then  Camera alert appears immediately after over the select photos window.

Please let me know if I am missing anything from my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: not at the same time but first it will show camera permission then another one 
i guess

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed yes I want exactly this functionality. Sorry if my question was not clear

Comment: posted the answer bellow :)

Comment: Please reopen my question.I am new to stack overflow.I am sorry if my question was not clear. I have edited it so that its more clear. It was closed within a very little time. I do not know the reason.

Comment: if you are new then use youtube to watch video of your question just copy and paste your question on youtube 
otherwise you never understand it by code 
so its my opinion to open youtube and learn

Comment: otherwise i can create an example  project  of ask permissions and mail you you can easily get

Answer (score 1):

first add these lines to info plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access camera!.</string>
```

and also this

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access photos.</string>
```

after that add this class in your project

```
import Photos
import UIKit
public extension PHPhotoLibrary {
static func execute(controller: UIViewController,
                   onAccessHasBeenGranted: @escaping () -> Void,
                   onAccessHasBeenDenied: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

  let onDeniedOrRestricted = onAccessHasBeenDenied ?? {
     let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "We were unable to load your album groups. Sorry!",
        message: "You can enable access in Privacy Settings",
        preferredStyle: .alert)
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
           UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)
        }
     }))
     controller.present(alert, animated: true)
  }

  let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
  switch status {
  case .notDetermined:
     onNotDetermined(onDeniedOrRestricted, onAccessHasBeenGranted)
  case .denied, .restricted:
     onDeniedOrRestricted()
  case .authorized:
     onAccessHasBeenGranted()
  case .limited:
    onAccessHasBeenGranted()
  @unknown default:
     fatalError("PHPhotoLibrary::execute - \"Unknown case\"")
  }


 }
}

private func onNotDetermined(_ onDeniedOrRestricted: @escaping (()->Void), _ onAuthorized: @escaping (()->Void)) {


PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ status in
switch status {
  case .notDetermined:
     onNotDetermined(onDeniedOrRestricted, onAuthorized)
  case .denied, .restricted:
     onDeniedOrRestricted()
  case .authorized:
     onAuthorized()
 case .limited:
    onAuthorized()
  @unknown default:
     fatalError("PHPhotoLibrary::execute - \"Unknown case\"")
  }
 })
}
```

how to use it inside button or viewdidload etc

```
PHPhotoLibrary.execute(controller: self, onAccessHasBeenGranted: {
// access granted... 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add camera and photo gallery permission both one after another. You just have to add this key in info.plist -

`<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key> <string>Mention reason to access camera</string>`

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Mention reason to access photo Library</string>
```

and once it is added you have to add the following code in Appdelegate or in view controller you need to ask permission -

```
func askForCameraPermission() {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
            if response {
                //access granted
            } else {

            }
        }        
}

func askForPhotoLibraryPermission() {
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        if photos == .notDetermined {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                if status == .authorized{
                    //access granted
                } else {}
            })
        }
}
```